# IP used in the HELO request

Tags: email, exim, transip

I'm currently working on setting up my new VPS in a way so my emails dont get into the spam folders (ie Gmail, Hotmail etc). For all this to happen, all the DNS/SMTP configurations need to be setup correctly. Using mail-tester.com I've achieved a 8.2 out of 10 of which, there's one certain thing I just can't solve.

You can find my mail-tester results here: http://www.mail-tester.com/web-dWaMuK

**Problem:**

```
-1  FSL_HELO_BARE_IP_2  IP used in the HELO request
The hostname must be a domain name, not an IP-address
-0.865  RCVD_NUMERIC_HELO   Received: contains an IP address used for HELO
```

I have a VPS from TransIP running on CENTOS 7.1 with a WHM/cPanel setup.

I went through several tutorials to set it up correctly and this is what I have done so far:

- Gave the VPS a hostname
- setup the hostname as the rDNS and gave it an A record in the DNS
- SPF and DKIM are valid, it passes the test.
- Configured the EXIM in the WHM as explained here: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Configure+Exim%27s+Outgoing+IP+Address

According to some googling the answer would be to setup a hostname as the rDNS (which I did), but for some reason it still sees the IP.

What am I overlooking?

**P.S. the rDNS in the header and mail-tester report still needs to be refreshed to the correct rDNS (charlotte.studiomod.us). But even if it refreshes to the correct rDNS, I still get the same error.**

This is what the header of the email displays:

```
Received: by mail-tester.com (Postfix, from userid 500) id 06909A8A7E;
    Tue, 22 Dec 2015 21:44:46 +0100 (CET)
Authentication-Results: mail-tester.com; dkim=pass  reason="2048-bit key;
 unprotected key"   header.d=adamkramer.nl header.i=@adamkramer.nl
 header.b=brI/kj1q; dkim-adsp=pass; dkim-atps=neutral
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on mail-tester.com
X-Spam-Level: *
X-Spam-Status: No/1.8/5.0
X-Spam-Test-Scores: DKIM_SIGNED=0.1,DKIM_VALID=-0.1,DKIM_VALID_AU=-0.1,
    FSL_HELO_BARE_IP_2=1,RCVD_NUMERIC_HELO=0.865,SPF_PASS=-0.001
X-Spam-Last-External-IP: 149.210.247.192
X-Spam-Last-External-HELO: charlotte.studiomod.us
X-Spam-Last-External-rDNS: studiomod.us
X-Spam-Date-of-Scan: Tue, 22 Dec 2015 21:44:46 +0100
X-Spam-Report: * -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record   *  0.9
 RCVD_NUMERIC_HELO Received: contains an IP address used for HELO   *  0.1
 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily    *     
 valid  * -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
 author's   *       domain  * -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid
 DKIM or DK signature   *  1.0 FSL_HELO_BARE_IP_2 No description available.
Received-SPF: Pass (sender SPF authorized) identity=mailfrom;
 client-ip=149.210.247.192; helo=charlotte.studiomod.us;
 envelope-from=hi@adamkramer.nl; receiver=web-dwamuk@mail-tester.com
Authentication-Results: mail-tester.com; dmarc=none
 header.from=adamkramer.nl
Received: from charlotte.studiomod.us (studiomod.us [149.210.247.192])
    by mail-tester.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id C68D7A6B05
    for <web-dWaMuK@mail-tester.com>; Tue, 22 Dec 2015 21:44:44 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=adamkramer.nl; s=default; h=Message-ID:Subject:To:From:Date:
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version;
    bh=sppGM44qRiT1lp/+/J/v0fXBV/FUiCZW3eSPSLRfKZ0=;
 b=brI/kj1qmqbYsbC6FyBpERQHyf
    /6DPq0KZ9zfVNSHJdZ4O66aUTdFGrWKLlLsOWTXWJVc7iDX78cLJHMvkE0jqUKfQINKJGMm2K4r
    3Q
    OP3aKPoNuLppE1rd4HW80KLUBgS0rQtTg4lzcf1kyPpZoZMGMXlKyNBMoiq5Ifqfw6kbMoLM5F2
    sS
    jEnHrjQhLgVaPm3Ujei+jrhnmD8Ey0KWZT5AxrLBf5MvLKQxaaioOx+bewm8Lu/CcqvkBLUxmYI
    /m
    V0BRGmEN4I6o5P+CJg7AjtugsnzNlBxqs8Xs8X/hmCtXKSo1pjptn0DTczSVAgzmExCKYI89S9a
    D5  5R+ZVFmw==;
Received: from [::1] (port=41793 helo=149.210.247.192)
    by charlotte.studiomod.us
    with esmtpa (Exim 4.86) (envelope-from <hi@adamkramer.nl>)
    id 1aBTnj-0004ke-2M for web-dWaMuK@mail-tester.com;
    Tue, 22 Dec 2015 21:44:55 +0100
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 22 Dec 2015 21:44:54 +0100
From: Adam Kramer <hi@adamkramer.nl>
To: web-dWaMuK@mail-tester.com
Subject: Testing my email
Message-ID: <6c2118033c11b8be94dd356a2dde55a4@adamkramer.nl>
X-Sender: hi@adamkramer.nl
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.0.6
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with
 any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - charlotte.studiomod.us
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - mail-tester.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - adamkramer.nl
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: charlotte.studiomod.us: authenticated_id:
 hi@adamkramer.nl
X-Authenticated-Sender: charlotte.studiomod.us: hi@adamkramer.nl
Return-Path: hi@adamkramer.nl
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Testing this to see if it works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Received header that has a numerical HELO is not the one with the HELO provided by Exim. Exim is sending `charlotte.studiomod.us`.

The HELO that is being complained about is the one provided by the program you are using to send your mail: roundcube.

Selecting only `Received` headers from your mail makes this easier to see: the first line is internal to mail-tester, the second is mail-tester saying that it got the mail from charlotte (format is HELO (rDNS [IP]), the third is charlotte saying it got the mail from roundcube, and this last one is the only one saying that the helo is the IP address.

```
Received: by mail-tester.com (Postfix, from userid 500) id 06909A8A7E;
    Tue, 22 Dec 2015 21:44:46 +0100 (CET)
Received: from charlotte.studiomod.us (studiomod.us [149.210.247.192])
    by mail-tester.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id C68D7A6B05
    for <web-dWaMuK@mail-tester.com>; Tue, 22 Dec 2015 21:44:44 +0100 (CET)
Received: from [::1] (port=41793 helo=149.210.247.192)
    by charlotte.studiomod.us
    with esmtpa (Exim 4.86) (envelope-from <hi@adamkramer.nl>)
    id 1aBTnj-0004ke-2M for web-dWaMuK@mail-tester.com;
    Tue, 22 Dec 2015 21:44:55 +0100
```

Comment: So the solution is as simple as using a different mail program to send emails with? Or is it possible to correct this?

Comment: You must correct the roundcube configuration (only if you want to use roundcube, of course, but as far as I know roundcube is a good choice of webmail). It seems that roundcube uses "server_name" as HELO. Best bet would be to look for the IP in the roundcube configuration and replace it with either `charlotte.studiomod.us` or `localhost`.

Comment: I tried it with a different webmail service and I actually got a 10/10 on mail-tester.com. Never thought this would be a possible issue. Thank you so much! Ill look into changing the configuration of roundcube and assuming this is the solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Changed the smtp helo settings of roundcube to the hostname and aced the mail-tester test. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the accept. I've edited my answer to explain a bit more.